# SQL table structure

Tags: t-sql, data-structures, database-design

I am starting a new project that will handle surveys and reviews. At this point I am trying to figure out what would be the best sql table structure to store and handle such information.

Basically, the survey will contain ratings, text reviews and additional optional information available for clients to share. Now I am thinking of either storing each information in a separate column or maybe merge all this data and store it as an XML in one column.

I am not sure what would be a better solution, but I have the following issues on my mind:
- would possible increase of information collected would be a problem in case of single XML column
- would a single XML column have any serious impact on performance when extracting and handling information from xml column

Comment: There's been a lot of chat about a big-ole XML field. This solves many problems for you, but take it from someone who learned the hard way. Just because SQL **can** query XML type columns does not mean it does so efficiently (read: quickly) when there are many rows in the table. You will end up surfacing columns anyway! I would never revisit that error in judgement. I recommend you think hard before you learn for yourself. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to keep this simple, you have two choices: dyanmic or static surveys.

Dynamic surveys would look like this:
[image: dynamic]

Not only would reporting be more complicated, but so would the UI. The number of questions is unknown and you would eventually need logic to handle order, grouping, and data types.

Static surveys would look more like this:
[image: static]

Although you certainly give up some flexibility, the solution (including reports) is considerably simpler. You need not handle order, grouping, or data types (at least dynamically).

I like to argue that "Simplicity is the best Design" in almost everything.

Since I cannot know your requirements in detail, I cannot assume which is the better fit. But I can tell you this, the dynamic is often built when the static is sufficient.

Best of luck!

Comment: @John, There are **so** many tools already written that do this; are you sure you want to write it yet again? I know I would, but are you sure **you** want to?

Answer (score 3):

If you ever have a reason to query on a single piece of info, or update it alone, then don't store that data in XML, but instead as a separate column.

It is rare, IMO, that storing XML (or any other composite type of data) is a good idea in a DB.  Although there are always exceptions.

Comment: On the other hand, does it mean that any new piece of info would demand a new column? What if there is a need of having a couple of different survey types...New table for each survey type or merging columns into one giant table, both does not sound like a good solution..

Comment: If you need to be able to search on the new data, then a new table (or table structure) is the correct answer, regardless of whether it existed in the original design.

Comment: We have a problem. "I know! Lets solve it with XML!" Great, now we have two problems

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to fight with a relational database that expects relational data you probably want reasonably normalized data.  I don't see in your case what advantage the XML would give you.  If you have multiple values entered in the survey, you probably want another table for survey entries with a foreign key to the survey.

If this is going to be a relatively extensive application you might think about a table for survey definition, a table for survey question, a table for survey response, and a table for survey question response.  If the survey data can be multiple types, you might need a table for each kind of question that might be asked, though in some cases a column might do.

EDIT - I think you would *at least* have one row per answer to a question.  If the answer is complex (doesn't correspond to just one instance of a simple data type) it might actually be multiple rows (though denormalizing into multiple columns is probably O.K. if the number of columns is small and fixed).  If an answer to one question needs to be stored in multiple rows, you would almost certainly end up with one table that represents the answer, and has one row per answer, plus another table that represents pieces of the answer, and has one row per piece.

If the reason you are considering XML is that the answers are going to be of very different types (for example, a review with a rating, a title, a header, a body, and a comments section for one question; a list of hyperlinks for another question, etc.) then the answer table might actually have to be several tables, so that you can model the data for each type of question.  That would be a pretty complicated case though.

Hopefully one row per response, in a single table, would be sufficient.

Comment: But the problem is that one survey type would contain more then one question. If we skip the way I will store survey questions, possible answers etc. and concentrate how to store user response, according to your suggestions I should break down survey responses in multiple rows instead of multiple columns. Did I get it right?

Answer (score 0):

To piggyback off of Flimzy's answer, you want to simply store the data in the database and not a specific format (i.e. XML).  You might a requirement at the moment for XML, but tomorrow it might be a CSV or a fixed width DAT file.  Also, if you store just the data, then you can use the "power" of the database to search on specific columns of information and then return it as XML, if desired.